# Change detection doesn't happen in synchronous codes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was working on a component that has a button which toggles a boolean. This boolean is supposed to determine if a child component in the HTML need to re-render or not, since I want the `ngOnInit` function in the child to be re-run.

The situation is described in the app component here: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-qxtm8

The `app.component` is the parent and `second.component` is the child.

I have tried three different solutions. They are `onTestClickOne`, `onTestClickTwo`, and `onTestClickThree` in `app.component.ts`. `onTestClickOne` and `onTestClickTwo` successfully re-triggers the `ngOnInit` in the child component. We can see the console log in it is printed on the console whenever I click the corresponding buttons. However, `onTestClickThree` didn't work.

I'm not 100% sure why `onTestClickThree` didn't work, and `onTestClickTwo` did.

My guesses are the following:

1. `onTestClickTwo` works because the change detection in Angular is run after the event handler has been executed. So, it will detect the boolean has been set to true. After that, the event loop will get the callback of the setTimeout and put it into the stack. Angular will execute change detection after finishing the callback.
2. `onTestClickThree` didn't work because, by the time Angular runs change detection, the boolean is already true. Angular doesn't know that it has been changed.

Comment: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/

Answer (score 0):

Let's tackle the main issue there, which is your design : why would you re-render the component to trigger `ngOnInit` again ?

Sure, in the case of your example, that's no big deal. But what happens for a fully coded component, making http calls, having children and all ? That will cause some severe performance issues.

Instead of re-rendering the component, you should use a function to do that.

If the event (that is initially supposed to re-render the component) comes from the child, then use an `@Output`. If it comes from the parent, use a `@ViewChild` reference.

[As you can see](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-6jfv6) it works well, without any detection issue.